# Rails - Show route is used instead of one I have defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes

I am using AJAX to listen for a change to a dropdown on my form called question_language_id, when this is changed I want to run some javascript to make some changes to my form.

The problem I am having is that rails goes straight to the Show action rather than my `update_questions_direction` action which is causing the error in show action `'Question could not be found with id=update_questions_direction'.`

The ordering of rake routes doesn't seem to change this.

my AJAX call is as follows:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#question_language_id', (evt) ->
$.ajax 'update_questions_direction',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'script'
  data: {"language_id": $("#question_language_id option:selected").val()}
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log("Direction was changed")
```

from routes.rb:

```
get 'questions/update_questions_direction', as: 'update_questions_direction'


resources :categories do
  resources :questions do
      resources :answers
      member do
          get :quizzes
      end
  end
end
```

the relevant output from rake routes:

```
update_questions_direction GET    /questions/update_questions_direction(.:format)                            questions#update_questions_direction
category_question GET    /categories/:category_id/questions/:id(.:format)                           questions#show
```

I cannot understand why this is happening - why does rails think update_questions_direction is the id?

The error that I get is:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in QuestionsController#show
Couldn't find Question with 'id'=update_questions_direction
```

I would really appreciate any help with this, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a relative path in your `ajax` call, so the request is put to a path, relative to the current path you're in. And if your current path is `/categories/1/questions`, it's no mystery why it wants to go to `/categories/1/questions/update_questions_direction` and can't find that `id` in the database. 
The quickest solution is to replace the relative path with an absolute:

```
$.ajax '/questions/update_questions_direction',
```

Comment: Thank you so much! worked perfectly and thank you for your explanation